# Best way to get all environment variables starting with specific prefix in python

Tags: python, configuration, environment-variables

I want to get all the environment variables starting with a specific prefix and save them (without prefix) into a dictionary. Is there any better way than getting all the `os.environ` variables and searching through them?
I also need those to be merged with a config file, so if you know any library in python which is like Viper in go (which handles both environment variables and config files and merging of them with priority), it will be a huge help.

UPDATE:

my configs are not simple app config, they are users config with some structures in it, so it's not a simple key value pair. It also might be in different formats, such as YAML, INI, JSON, etc.

Comment: I think you'll have to search `os.environ`. It can be done in one line though: `{key.replace(...): val for key, val in os.environ.items() if key.startswith(...)}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the env vars from .env file or from terminal than `environs` package is the best

```
export KAFKA_HOST=kafka
export KAFKA_PORT=9092
```

Python code to read all the env variables starting with `KAFKA_`

```
from environs import Env
env = Env()
env.read_env()
with env.prefixed("KAFKA_"):
     print(env("HOST"))
     print(env("PORT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any other solution that using `os.environ` to load your environment variable and loop through them. It would look something like:

```
import os
import re

# Replace PREF by the prefix you want
prefix="PREF"
myPattern = re.compile(r'{prefix}\w+'.format(prefix=prefix))
my_env_variables = {key.replace(prefix,''):val for key, val in os.environ.items() if myPattern.match(key)}

print(my_env_variables)
```

Regarding config files management, I warmly recommend the **python-dotenv** library: [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Answer (score 0):

Searching through os.environ is going to be the best way.

```
from typing import Dict
import os

prefix: str = "MY_PREFIX_"
variables: Dict[str, str] = {}
for key, value in os.environ.items():
    if key[:len(prefix)] == prefix:
        variables[key[len(prefix):]] = value
```